# How to change the color of the 2D texture dynamically using arcore & sceneform

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I am working on an AR application using ARCore and Sceneform. I want to add texture to lips .Am applying lip color using arcore & sceneform .Is it possible to change the color of the texture dynamically or we need to create separate .png file for different colors.
Should I create separate  R.drawable.makeupforlips file for each color

```
Texture.builder()
   .setSource(this, R.drawable.makeupforlips)
   .setUsage(Texture.Usage.COLOR)
   .build()
   .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture = texture);
```

addOnUpdateListener:

```
    for (AugmentedFace face: faceList) {

if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {

    AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
    faceNode.setParent(scene);
    // faceNode.setFaceRegionsRenderable(faceRegionsRenderable);
    faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture);
    faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
}
```

}